# Conditional for post type inside loop (recent posts)

Tags: custom-post-types

I am working on an owl carousel integration to WP.

I have it drawing from an array of post types but now I would like to show a custom string based on which post type it is

```
<div class="owl-carousel">

    <?php $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => array('resources', 'videos', 'webinars'), 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby'=> 'ASC')); ?> 
    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="owl-recent-post"> 

        <a href="<?php print get_permalink($post->ID) ?>">
            <?php echo the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
        <div class="owl-post-text">
            <h4><?php print get_the_title(); ?></h4>
            <?php
                if ($post->post_type == "resources") {
                    echo 'Resource Specific Stuff';
                }
            ?>
            <a class="btn " href="<?php print get_permalink($post->ID) ?>">More</a>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

I'm using the if statement but getting no results (have double checked the naming of the post type so it seems my method is wrong) How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$post` is a global variable, not a super global, you need to state that you're intending to use it before doing so:

```
global $post;
```

But in this case, it would be easier to use:

```
get_post_type();
```

Some other notes:

- You never do an `if ( have_posts() )` check
- There's no cleanup call to `wp_reset_postdata()` which will cause problems for any use of the main query after this carousel
- `'posts_per_page' => -1` could lead to some terrifying results, always set an upper bound, even if it's a silly one you'll never reach, such as 50 or 100, this way you don't end up with that super laggy edge case. I would recommend 10, after all most people never go past the first slide, why would they look at the 11th?
- Use `echo` or use `print` but stick to one, don't mix and match
- If a post has no featured image then it will be impossible to click through, use `has_post_thumbnail` and put a placeholder in if there isn't one